# 内部LANで使用するhttpのポート番号

Tags: http

httpを80番から変更したものを内部LANで使用したいと思っています。
よく使われるのは8080番ですが、一般的に複数ポート番号を用意したいとき何番を使うのが一般的なのでしょうか？

dockerを使って100ポート数の違う番号でhttpを使用したいと思っています。
あまりにも変な番号をつけて不具合や一般的には違うという事になりたくないなと思いまして質問させていただいています。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8080の他に、10080もよく使われます。複数必要な場合は8081,8082...のように採番するのが一般的だと思います。

ただ、100というと数が多すぎるので、ポートだけでなく複数のIPアドレスに分割することを検討した方がいいように思います。まさか1コンテナということはないでしょうから、コンテナを複数ホストに分割するときにも楽になります。

Comment: 有用な情報助かります。もちろん複数ホストですので、8080、8081・・・で使っていきたいと思います。